# Is there a way to make individual cells in a flextable in R have rounded corners?

Tags: r, styles, flextable

Is there any way to make cells in flextable have rounded edges/borders? Haven't stumbled upon a way to do it so far, so any of you guys have any idea?

NB: Just like the green and red cells in the table provided.

OBS: Couldn't add a picture due to lack of reputation - but as the green coloured cells in the table on this website: https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/prettytables

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider including a **minimal** reproducible question with the data and code you have tried. Check out [mre] and [ask]

Comment: To be honest, I haven't really tried anything.

I used:

CVTable <- bg(CVTable, i = 1:23, j = 2:3, bg = c(customGreen), part = "body")

To give some of the cells a green background. That worked perfectly, but as the cells are still 'square'-formed, I'm not entirely happy with it. I want rounded edges of the cells. I cannot seem to find any flextable-documentation that allows me to create round-edged cells, but if anyone in here has any idea how to go about it, it would be amazing!

Comment: Have you looked at the `formattable` package?